# Understanding return statement in the function finding the median of numbers

Tags: python, list, return-value, median

I have this function:

```
def median(numbers):
    middle = int(len(numbers)/2)
    return numbers[middle]

print(median([4, 5, 6, 7, 8]))
```

The writing style of this line is a bit confusing for me:

```
return numbers[middle]
```

If I am not mistaken it returns the input numbers' order in a list.
Is there a different way to read this line?

Comment: I'm not sure if that is what you asked, but the return value of your function is the value in the `middle` index inside `numbers`

Comment: What do you mean by " the input numbers' order in a list"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`numbers[middle]` is slicing of the list, which returns the element at `middle` position. It returns a single element, which is at the `middle` index, starting from 0.

Comment: Yes, it is. Is there other way to demonstrate it?

Comment: I wouldn't call `numbers[middle]` strictly slicing. It just refers to a particular element of a list at index `middle`.

Answer (score 0):

This is the evaluation:

```
middle = int(len(numbers)/2)
middle = int(5/2)
middle = int(2.5) # or int(2) depending on Python version
middle = 2

numbers[middle]
numbers[2]
6
```

Answer (score 0):

The `middle` corresponds to the index at the middle of your `numbers` list. To find the median of the list, you can try to sort it first using `numbers.sort()`, like this:

```
def median(numbers):
    numbers.sort()
    middle = int(len(numbers)/2)
    return numbers[middle]
```

As an example, if `numbers = [1,2,3,4,5,6]`, `len(numbers)` will evaluate to 6, which will be halved to 3 to define the `middle` index. Given that and knowing that a python list starting index is 0, the line `return numbers[middle]` will return the fourth element, which is 4.